# Extracting bug report data from a specific project

Tags: dataframe, bugzilla

When is search over a bugzilla for a specific project, i download the result of the search as CSV file. However, the CSV file data is too limited.  Is there any other better way to get bug report data?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to extract all bug report data for a certain project. The project use bugzilla for recording and tracking bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the results of a search as XML which has all the bug data except attachments.

Comment: thank you for your answer! bugzilla reporting provide two options to download the data: CSV or XML.  But the problem is that it is limited to 10000 instances. it cannot generate a report that has larger than 10000 instances.

Comment: There is a parameter (max_search_results) that controls the number of items in the result. You could increase this. Note that this only affects the HTML format of search results--CSV, XML, and other formats are exempted.